# SerialPort IOException Kick CashDrawer C#

Tags: c#, ioexception

I found the Drawer Kick Command Codes for Epson TM-U Series Receipt Printer and was assign as COM1 via Epson Virtual Port.

When I about to run the software I got an IOExecption citing that "The Parameter is Incorrect"

```
System.IO.IOException was caught
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=The parameter is incorrect.

  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.IO.Ports.InternalResources.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String str)
       at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.InitializeDCB(Int32 baudRate, Parity parity, Int32 dataBits, StopBits stopBits, Boolean discardNull)
       at System.IO.Ports.SerialStream..ctor(String portName, Int32 baudRate, Parity parity, Int32 dataBits, StopBits stopBits, Int32 readTimeout, Int32 writeTimeout, Handshake handshake, Boolean dtrEnable, Boolean rtsEnable, Boolean discardNull, Byte parityReplace)
       at System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Open()
       at nPOSProj.Conf.Drawer.Open() in C:\sampleProj\Conf\Drawer.cs:line 21
  InnerException:
```

Based In My Code

```
        private SerialPort sp;
        public void Open()
        {
            try
            {
                Byte[] cashDrawerCmd = { 27, 112, 0, 25, 250 }; // TM-U Command Codes For Opening the Cash Drawer
                sp = new SerialPort();
                sp.PortName = "COM1";

                sp.BaudRate = 9600;
                sp.DataBits = 8;
                sp.Parity = Parity.None;
                sp.StopBits = StopBits.One;
                sp.Handshake = Handshake.None;
                // Opening
                sp.Open();
                sp.Write(cashDrawerCmd, 0, cashDrawerCmd.Length);
                sp.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                sp.Close();
            }
        }
```

I Don't Know which Parameter is not right. Do I have to Specify also the databits, stopbits parameters based on the StackTrace?

Comment: If the exception is caught, how can `sp.Close` work when its out of scope. Also, Is the printer not connected to  `LPT1:` ?

Comment: Never use handshaking (hardware or software) it is obsolete so set to NONE.  Also Open serial port after all the parameters are set.  I don't think any of the parameters are wrong.  The Epison Device has the port opened so you cannot open the port.  You have to disable the Epison device from automatically opening the port.

Comment: You should set the Baud, databits, parity, stop bits and handshake before opening the port.

Comment: @PatrickAllwood I try to set the baud, databits, parity, stop bits and handshake then I do the sp.Open();

I receive the same StackTrace. I don't know if something wrong with my code.

Comment: Try checking if the serial port is already open, if it is, close it and reopen it again with the correct settings. Virtual ports results in virtual errors due to invalid settings, check the encodings, use portmon to diagnose and confirm if its indeed opening/closing.

Comment: also, one final thing, SerialPort is horribly broken under .NET. Read [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.open.aspx)